# Scala Macros: Checking if a Java Field is marked as transient

Tags: scala, scala-macros

How can I check for the **ACC_TRANSIENT** flag on a field of a Java Class using a Scala Macro?

**TermSymbol** has methods like *isPrivate* & *isProtected* but doesn't have any sort of *isTransient* method.

### Checking Transient for Scala

For a Scala class you use the **@transient** annotation which generates a field with the **ACC_TRANSIENT** flag:

```
class ScalaExample {
  @transient protected var ignoredField: String = null
}
```

In the classfile you end up with:

```
  private transient java.lang.String ignoredField;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_TRANSIENT
```

And then in a Macro I can see the @transient annotation:

```
scala> typeOf[ScalaExample].member(TermName("ignoredField")).asTerm.accessed.annotations
res0: List[universe.Annotation] = List(scala.transient)
```

### Checking transient for Java?

However if I have a Java Class:

```
public class JavaExample {
  protected transient String ignoredField;
}
```

Which produces similar bytecode (the field is protected instead of private):

```
  protected transient java.lang.String ignoredField;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PROTECTED, ACC_TRANSIENT
```

There are no annotations:

```
scala> typeOf[JavaExample].member(TermName("ignoredField")).asTerm.accessed.annotations
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: variable ignoredField
  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.accessed(Symbols.scala:1978)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.accessed(Symbols.scala:1974)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TermSymbol.accessed(Symbols.scala:2658)
  ... 43 elided

scala> typeOf[JavaExample].member(TermName("ignoredField")).asTerm.annotations
res2: List[universe.Annotation] = List()
```

I realize that for the Scala class the **@transient** annotation is probably being read out of the ScalaSignature instead of the **ACC_TRANSIENT** flag which is why it doesn't show up for the java class.

### Possible Workaround / Hack

Using Scala Runtime Reflection I can get the java.lang.Class for JavaExample and then use Java reflection to check for the **ACC_TRANSIENT** flag using java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isTransient(...).  But this doesn't seem ideal for a Macro using Compile Time Reflection.  I also haven't figured out how to get it working in a Macro yet so I'm not sure if its even possible.

Comment: One small pointer: Java doesn't know anything about accessors in Scala's sense, so you don't want `.accessed` in there. I'm not sure whether there's a way to read whether the Java field is transient off the symbol—I don't think so, though.

Answer (score 2):

## Possible Workaround / Hack Solution

I ended up implementing the Possible Workaround / Hack mentioned in the question:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier
import java.net.URLClassLoader
import scala.reflect.macros._

abstract class MacroHelpers { self =>
  val ctx: Context
  import ctx.universe._

  private lazy val classLoader: ClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(ctx.classPath.toArray)

  def isJavaTransient(sym: Symbol): Boolean = {
    if (!sym.isJava || !sym.isTerm || !sym.asTerm.isVar) return false
    val className: String = sym.owner.asClass.fullName
    val clazz: Class[_] = classLoader.loadClass(className)  
    Modifier.isTransient(clazz.getDeclaredField(sym.name.decoded).getModifiers())
  }
}
```

This seems to work fine for me using both Scala 2.10.4 and 2.11.1.  If you are using your Macro in a mixed Scala/Java project and are trying to inspect the Java classes in the project then I think you need `CompileOrder.JavaThenScala` in your build.sbt to make sure the Java classes show up on the classpath before the Macro runs:

```
compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala
```

Comment: This is a compiler bug. I've just filed it in the Issue Tracker. Thanks for the workaround. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10042

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Scala 2.12.4 via this pull request:  https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5991

Comment: Yes, it was fixed recently.